# How do I connect to MY full node using RPC

Tags: parity, json-rpc, nodes

I have a full node(**Parity**) running at home. I know I can trust this node. How would I go about connecting to it from another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Using `geth` and having rpc enabled on your node you can:

```
geth attach --rpc=http://your_ip:your_port
```

Or, using the [MIST](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) wallet, you can connect to it

```
yarn dev:electron --rpc http://your_ip:your_host
```

Or, using [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/), you can connect to it from your code like:

```
 web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://your_ip:your_port"));
```

Comment: So if i had a light node running(parity) what would I do? If you could edit it with that I'll accept this helpful answer :).

Comment: what's your home server IP and port that you want to connect to?